# Fetch Request returning {( //value )} instead of just value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, relationship

I am having an extremely hard time figuring out how to extract relationship values between entities.  I have a Food entity and a Meal entity.  For demonstration purposes I simply listed 1 attribute for each.  A title for Meal, and protein for Food.  My relationships are meal and food with inverse relationship, many to many.  What I want to be able to do is, fetch a Meal and return the protein value associated with that meal.  I will be fetching Meals by Date eventually and then pulling nutrition information from that Meal.  The solution I have found is returning more than just the value as you can see by the picture of the simulator label.  Please any help would be very appreciated!  I have a feeling there is an easier way to do what I am trying to do but I have been searching for hours and cant figure it out.

I tried posting images but it wont let me so I will post my code and what is happening.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    //================================
    //CREATE MEAL AND FOOD
    //================================
    let newMeal = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Meal", into: context) as! Meal
    newMeal.title = "Meal 1"

    let newFood = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Food", into: context) as! Food
    newFood.protein = "20"
    newFood.setValue(newMeal, forKey: "meal")

    //================================
    //FETCH REQUEST
    //================================
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Meal")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        //===============================
        //EXTRACT RELATIONSHIP DATA
        //==============================
        let results = try context.fetch(request) as NSArray
        for res in results {
            let data = res as! Meal
            let item = data.food
            let strs = item.value(forKey: "protein")
            self.label.text = "\(strs)"
        }
    } catch {
        print ("error")
    }   
}
```

My label is displaying this...

{(
   20
)}

I need to simply pull the '20' out.  Trying to set the label.text value to str as! string wont work either.  Any guidance??  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Will the following do?

```
self.label.text = strs
```

Comment: Can you check the type of "item" when tracing? What is it?

Comment: What variable are you referring to?

Comment: Let item = data.food (food is the relationship variable between the 2 entities)

Comment: Check the type of "strs". I guess it is a set.

Comment: You can check your data model (in "Meal.h"), and convert "item" to a string based on type of "food" in class "Meal", and then assign it to the label.text.

Comment: If i declare a global variable 'item' as String it wont let me set data.food equal to it since data.food is of type NSSet

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.....

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var item:NSSet = []
var strs:NSSet = []

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    //================================
    //CREATE MEAL AND FOOD
    //================================
    let newMeal = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Meal", into: context) as! Meal
    newMeal.title = "Meal 1"

    let newFood = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Food", into: context) as! Food
    newFood.protein = "20"
    newFood.setValue(newMeal, forKey: "meal")

    //================================
    //FETCH REQUEST
    //================================
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Meal")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        //===============================
        //EXTRACT RELATIONSHIP DATA
        //==============================
        let results = try context.fetch(request) as! [Meal]
        for res in results {

            item = res.food

            strs = item.value(forKey: "protein") as! NSSet
            let array = strs.allObjects
            print(array[0])

            self.label.text = String(format: "%@", array[0] as! CVarArg)
        }
    } catch {
        print ("error")
    }   
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Thanks for the help